# Ionic 5: PWA ionicon icons disappear

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic5, ionicons

This is a recent Angular Ionic `tabs` project created with `ionic cli`. I use `<ion-icon></ion-icon>` in HTML and icons show correctly. But if I install the PWA on my phone (`Add to Homescreen`), I open the app later & icons are missing.

Assuming this might be a wrong caching setting in my service worker? Anyone have an idea? Or a working code snippet?

Looks like my icons get installed by npm and live here: `<app_root>\node_modules\@ionic\core\dist\ionic\svg`